# How to compile Pro*C with PostgreSQL?

Tags: c, oracle, postgresql, database-migration

I move from OracleDB to PostgreSQL.

I have many Oracle Pro*C files, how can I make PostgreSQL understand them ?

Maybe with [PostgreSQL C language functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, what you need is a precompiler for embedded SQL.

In PostgreSQL, that is [ECPG](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg.html).

Things probably won't work without slight changes, but it shouldn't be too bad.